# (Java) How can I sort an array of objects, and break ties between two objects?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

Say I have an object - `Team`. `Team` has three fields, `wins`, `losses` and `draws`.

If I have a few objects say `Team1`, `Team2`, `Team3`, where `Team1` has 3 wins, 2 losses, and 1 tie, `Team2` has 3 wins and 3 losses, and `Team3` has 2 wins, 3 losses, and 1 tie.

Put all three teams in an array.

I am trying to sort (I know how to do this.. implement `Comparable`, override `compareTo()` use `Array.sort`) them by wins, and if two teams have the same wins, I want to then sort them by losses (and eventually a third field will be added to further break ties).

Should I write my own sort method? Can someone point me in the right direction because I have no clue where to go with this.

Comment: If you write a suitable `compareTo` (or a `Comparator`) you don't need to write your own sort.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick and helpful responses, I got it working both using a comparator and by modifying my existing compareTo method!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to Ben's answer, but a bit different, I often use the following pattern for clarity.  This is a **Comparator**, but the code for **Comparable** would be similar.

```
Comparator<Team> myComparator = new Comparator() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
      int result = t1.getWins() - t2.getWins();
      if (result == 0)
         result = t2.getLosses() - t1.getLosses();
      if (result == 0)
         ... more tests here

      return result;
   }

};
```

Note that taking the difference of two integers *might* overflow in *extreme* cases, so a more robust variation would use `Integer.compare(t1.getWins(),  t2.getWins())`.  However, in this case, it is unlikely that your teams will have more than 2^31 wins or losses.  :-)

To use this, go

```
Arrays.sort(myArrayOfTeams, myComparator);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have the good fortune to be using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), then you could just do this:

```
ArrayList<Team> teams = myTeams();

Collections.sort(teams,
    Comparator.comparingInt(Team::getWins())
              .thenComparingInt(Team::getTies());
    );
```

Or if you are using an array:

```
Team[] teams = myTeams();

Arrays.sort(teams,
    Comparator.comparingInt(Team::getWins())
              .thenComparingInt(Team::getTies());
    );
```

This also makes it easier to sort by other things, such as the team's name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify Comparable to not only consider wins, but to consider ties, especially when wins occur.

So in your compareTo, add an if to check when wins are equal, and then inside that if do the check on losses.  Here you can even add in the check for draws as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your overridden compareTo() method, you would simply need to catch when the wins are equal and then assign it a preference based on losses so

```
compareTo(Team other){
    if(this.getWins() > other.getWins()){
        return 1;
    } else if(this.getWins() == other.getWins()){
        if(this.getLosses() < other.getLosses()){
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You could then add another else if in the inner loop to check if losses are equal, and in that if statement you would compare the ties, and if they are completely equal you would return a 0